# How to code the Web Api Route, Controller for texting

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-post, twilio

I need to create a REST API Web Service using MVC4 Web Api that will be consumed by Twilio. I need to be able to accept Twilio's HTTP POST for receiving SMS from the user and for responding. So if the user texts a word "Join" or "My Order" then they would call my API using the URL that I have given and I should be sending the Welcome Message for join and the Order List for the text "My Order" and so on. How the heck do I do that? Do I need a single controller or multiple? How would I route this? Please help. Totally lost :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Twilios HTTP requests are no different than any other HTTP client.  So if you want to use Web API as your Twilio SMS URL, then you would just create a Post method and in the method definition, specify the parameters you want to capture from the request.

Twilio sends along a bunch if info with each request, like the to & from phone numbers and the body of the message.  You can use model binding to grab this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string Body) {
    //your code here

    // if you want to return TwiML commands, use
    // us the TwilioResponse object

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, [your twiml]);
}
```

Twilio will made its request with an Accept header of text/xml, so WEb API should automatically try to return your TwiML commands as XML.

This blog post has more details on using Web API with Twilio:

http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/building-twilio-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I looked up that blog post example but was confused regarding the following code where they are initializing the XML. Do we need to do that and if so where would you put that code? I didnt get that part.         
      
       FilterConfig.RegisterHttpFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
MapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
GlobalConfiguration
.Configuration
.Formatters
.XmlFormatter
.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "text/xml");
GlobalConfiguration
.Configuration
.Formatters
.XmlFormatter
.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");